# Redux Store Props not Available in time for React Constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have been working with Redux & React for a few months. I usually always use Chrome with no issues. ( Endless bugs actually :) ).

When I started testing in Firefox I ran into an issue which I need some help with ... To know if there is a perfect way at dealing with this ...

Issue 
Redux Props for MapStateToProps are not yet available when the constructor gets called, which means I cannot construct my components state in the component constructor. These props become available swiftly afterwards in the render function. At this stage, it is too late because I cannot construct state in the render function (Could somehow work that, but wouldn't be good to approach right ?).

For the moment I am using the componentWillReceiveProps and duplicating my constructor function with one exception

Constructor function

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
//Loads of code named A
this.state = {state:A};
}
```

Component Will Receive Props Function

```
componentWillReceiveProps (){
//Loads of code named A
this.setState({state:A});
}
```

There may be an issue over overwriting my state here, but for my exact case here, its only displaying data, no UI changes happen... This doesn't appear correct method either way...

I read this article 
https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

I am not quite sure if I understand this fully. I did experiment with it a little with no working solutions.

Ideally, I need the constructor to pause until all redux store is populated which also doesn't make sense. Props arrays could be empty.

There are discussions on Slack but none seem to address this exactly. I tried googling issue but couldn't find exact issue addressed ...

I need the mapStateToProps props to construct my state. It is looking like I won't be able to do this and will need to totally refactor code to work more solely in the render function with loads of ternary operators and/or making calls to set state from the render function before the render returns.

Any thoughts on this issue?

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you need put the data you get from props into the component state?
As far as using the data there is no difference between the two except that you're more likely to get into trouble if you copy props to state (see link you posted).

```
const { A } = this.state;
const { A } = this.props;
```

If the data is coming via an async method then you should accommodate that in your render method.

```
render() {
  const { A } = this.props;
  if (!A) {
    return <LoadingIndicator />
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I understand. I did assume this to be the only way to do this. Suppose just wanted bounce it off someone else to be sure. So the constructor can't really be used for data which may take a while to arrive, more so for literals or readily available data only. I do apprieacte your help in clarifying this for me. 
Daniel

Comment: no worries at all.I like to think of components as movies, with a frame that can be rendered for each possible state, so it never blocks, it just renders for the data it has at that moment.